# ESD damage to old system

Tags: capacitor, esd, motherboard, static

I was doing a capacitor check on an old xbox motherboard. I always knew that you could damage a motherboard by touch but at the time either my mindset was off or overconfident in its supposed rarity.

For some reason I decided to smooth my fingers over the top of some electrolytic capacitors to check if the tops were flat and not domed.

I was also wearing socks and in a carpeted room, I was also walking around the room beforehand. Later on I felt a static shock when I unplugged a ethernet cable and touched the metal at the back.

Now my question is, how likely is it that I have cause damage to this old xbox and its components by touched the top of the caps?

Carpeted room, movement and socks part of the equation.

Comment: does it still work when you turn it on?

Comment: Likely? get a coin, heads or tails...

Comment: Still works when I turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the likelihood of you having caused damage is low.

Most of those large capacitors are connected to ground, or some low impedance to ground, and any static discharge into them will have been conducted away quite harmlessly.

That's not to say impossible, just unlikely.

Now, if you did that to the contacts of some connector, like a memory slot, while its disconnected from whatever it's supposed to be plugged into, that's a different story.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The system itself was not plugged in at the time and was sitting on my desk. Does that effect the grounding of the caps at all?

Comment: Ground connects everything together. If you raise ground potential, you raise everything's potential, and if you raise everything, there's no "difference" in potential anywhere that can cause damage. It's potential *difference* that kills things. So I'll say no, it still *probably* won't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you once again!

Comment: One last thing, so by touching a cap that is connected to ground, it raises everythings potential in line with any static that I may discharge, therefore damage will not happen as everything has the same potiential?